# MonoGame and normal windowed desktop application

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, monogame

I am trying to move all my XNA projects to Monogame. But in project templates I found only XAML and horrible metro application template. Is MonoGame support creating application in good old windowed mode for Windows 8? If yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your issue is.

MonoGame (as of 3.0's beta) adds a bunch of template projects to VS2010, including **MonoGame Application for Windows**. It runs by default as a windowed application, albeit a console one (so it creates a console window too) -- which is eeasily remedied.

**Edit:** I didn't realize you're asking about Windows 8 specifically. When you install the MonoGame 3.0 (beta), you'll find the Windows 8 assembly you probably need in `%program files%\MonoGame\v3.0\Assemblies\Windows8`. As of today (3.0 beta), you probably only need to add a reference to `MonoGame.Framework.Windows8.dll`

Comment: I forget to add that I mean windowed application for Windows 8 :-)

Comment: Just minute before you write previous comment I realized that you try to tell that I should use templates from vs2010 :-) Yes I have some problems with dlls especially with openal32... any advice for this?

Comment: done, for others find in folder ThirdParty/Libs and run oalinst.exe

Answer (score 0):

MonoGame.Framework.Windows8.dll is for Windows Metro, so basically for good old desktop-mode games, you have to use MonoGame.Framework.Windows.dll.

Answer (score 0):

For plain old windows desktop you can simply use XNA, as it is mostly the same as monogame. Also Monogame uses opengl, as i expirienced much troubles with it on windows 7 desktop